# How to compute SHA-1 of a big file (>50MB) in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, box

I'm trying to use [Box chunked-upload API](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#chunked-upload) from google apps script for a big file (>50MB).  I could create session and uploaded part files, but I got stuck to commit upload.

This API requires "Digest" header mandatorily, but I cannot compute the digest of the file since it's more than 50MB.

When I run the following code, apps script says "File big_file.bin exceeds the maximum file size."

```js
function test_compute_digest() {
  var big_file = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");  // >50MB file
  var sha1 = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, big_file.getBlob().getBytes()));
  Logger.log(sha1);
}
```

Is there any way to compute SHA-1 of a big file (>50MB) in google apps script?

Comment: You  probably should implement your own sha-1algo. There are plenty of Javascript libraries online. Use one, which is compatible with apps-script/ES3.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @TheMaster .  I'm not sure if Utilities.computeDigest() can work for a big file (>50MB), but firstly big_file.getBlob().getBytes() returns the error since blob size limit is 50MB in Google apps script.  I could upload part files by dividing the original file, but box commit upload API requires SHA-1 of the original file.